# How to create invisible objects to occlude other object in A-Frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe

i try to create a invisible objects to occlude other object in A-Frame. And i use MeshBasicMaterial and set colorWrite as false. But colorWrite in A-Frame behaves differently from Threejs.

here is my key code and screenshot.

**In Threejs**

```js
// cube inside
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
let texture = loader.load( 'assets/tiles.jpg' );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { transparent:true, map: texture, side: THREE.BackSide } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

// create invisible box to occlude inside box
const createCloakBox = (box) => {
  if (!box) {
    return;
  }
  const { width, height, depth } = box.geometry.parameters;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( width, height, depth);
  let material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({colorWrite: false});
  console.log(material1)
  let material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.BackSide});
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, [material1, material1, material1, material1, material2, material1]);

  cube.scale.set(1.01, 1.01, 1.01);

  scene.add(cube)
}
createCloakBox(cube)
```

[threejs demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdIPx.png)

**In A-Frame**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vconsole@latest/dist/vconsole.min.js"></script>
  

    <script>
      var vConsole = new window.VConsole();

      AFRAME.registerComponent('cloak', {
        init: function () {

          const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1);
          let material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            colorWrite: false,
          });
          let material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.BackSide});
          const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, [material1, material1, material1, material1, material2, material1]);
          cube.scale.set(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
          this.el.object3D.add(cube)
        },
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene >
      <a-assets>
        <img id="texture" src="./assets/tiles.jpg">
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity geometry="primitive: box; width: 1; height: 1; depth: 1" material="src: #texture; side: back;" cloak  position="0 0 -5"></a-entity>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

[A-Frame demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAy28.png)

is anyone know what cause this issue and how to solve it? Or maybe other way to create invisible objects to occlude other object. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fiddle with the [renderOrder](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.renderOrder) of the objects, but for whatever reason its not working.

A workaround would be changing the order of the nodes, so the cloak is before the cloaked object:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('cloak', {
    init: function() {
      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
      let windowM = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({colorWrite: false});
      let cloakM = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.BackSide});
      const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, [windowM, windowM, windowM, windowM, cloakM, windowM]);
      cube.scale.set(1.1, 1.2, 1.2);
      this.el.object3D.add(cube)
    },
  });
</script>

<a-scene>
  <a-sky color="#0000FF"></a-sky>
  <a-entity position="0 0.5 -5">
    <a-entity cloak></a-entity>
    <a-entity geometry="primitive: box; width: 1; height: 1; depth: 1" 
              material="color: green; side: back;"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: thank you for answer, now it can cloak the inside object, but the material which set colorWrite as false still has color, not like threejs is invisible, Do you know this issue?